# How do you force line spacing to be uniform when a line contains characters with vector or overdot?

Tags: formatting, text

A persistent problem I've run into is that certain character decorations within the text of a paragraph will often add extra line spacing even if there is already plenty of space between lines. This happens with things like vectors $\vec r$, overdots $\dot y$, and roots $\sqrt x$ but not to superscripts or subscripts. It is most apparent if one of these is in the middle of a large `Text` paragraph. The uneven line spacing looks rather unsightly and unprofessional.

[image]

I tried adding the option `LineSpacing -> {1.25, 0, 1.25}` to the Text cell but that doesn't seem to do anything. Even if I add more line spacing with something like `LineSpacing -> {1.5, 0, 1.5}` the character decorations still add height even though there is plenty of room for them.

I would like to keep the special characters in `TraditionalForm` so they match the style used in `InlineFormula` fields if possible.

Answer (score 2):

One quick idea would be to wrap a StyleBox around the FormBox'es (of the inline cells).
I just do this here once "by hand", but you can easily write a little program to do this.

```
   Manipulate[fs = s, {{s, 10, "fontsize"}, 9, 14, 1}]
CellPrint@Cell[TextData[{
     "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur \
    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt \
    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim \
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris \
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis ",
     Cell[BoxData[StyleBox[
         FormBox[
           SqrtBox["S"], TraditionalForm], FontSize -> Dynamic@fs]],
       FormatType -> "TraditionalForm"],
     "aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate \
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt \
    in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est \
    laborum."
    }], "Text"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]